# Is there any sdk or library available to implement dot lock like feature in my iphone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, locking

Can anyone suggest me some open source library or sdk to implement dot lock feature like android in my iphone app ?
I browsed through many such apps but was not able to find any sdk which i can use in my app.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, knock yourself out

http://cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android